# Google analytics referring traffic from subdomain name site

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I have two sites www.MyExample.com and OnlineStore.MyExample.com. I would like to track the traffic coming from www.MyExample.com to OnlineStore.MyExample.com under referring sources, but have not yet been successful.

I have tried using the following tags on my subdomain site but none of them would list WWW as a referring site:

`ga('create', 'UA-123456789-7', 'auto');
ga('create', 'UA-123456789-7', 'MyExample.com');
ga('create', 'UA-123456789-7', 'OnlineStore.MyExample.com');`

Any advice or pointer are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to treat the traffic from your main site into your subdomain as separate traffic (and not as part of the same session)? If so, maybe you can create a new property in GA and use a different tracking ID on the subdomain.

Comment: If this is a new account then myexample.com will automatically have been added to the referral exclusion list. I'm pretty sure that also excludes all of the subdomains.

Comment: I have set them up as different properties of the same account since they share the same domain name. If i understand your comments correctly, there is no way to track referral traffic (or traffic sources) from subdomains in the same GA account?